# WCF Issues with catching Inner Exception

Tags: wcf, exception, logging

I am trying to catch the inner exception of an exception and log it to a SQL Database table.  The code I have catches and logs exceptions to the SQL table without issue, but I never get an inner exception record even when the message for the exception says "See inner exception for details."  Can someone point me in the correct direction here as far as catching the inner exception is concerned?  Here is the code that is catching the exception, but not working for the inner exception.

```
                try
                {
                    context.CalculateFreight(xmldoc);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex.Message.ToString().Length > 2048)
                    {
                        ApplicationError myError = new ApplicationError();
                        myError.ErrorNumber = 1;
                        myError.ErrorSeverity = 1;
                        myError.ErrorState = 1;
                        myError.ErrorLine = 29;
                        myError.ErrorProcedure = "Web Service - ProcessShipping()";
                        myError.ErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString().Substring(0, 2047);
                        myError.ErrorDateTime = DateTime.Now;

                        context.ApplicationErrors.AddObject(myError);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ApplicationError myError = new ApplicationError();
                        myError.ErrorNumber = 1;
                        myError.ErrorSeverity = 1;
                        myError.ErrorState = 1;
                        myError.ErrorLine = 29;
                        myError.ErrorProcedure = "Web Service - ProcessShipping()";
                        myError.ErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
                        myError.ErrorDateTime = DateTime.Now;

                        context.ApplicationErrors.AddObject(myError);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    if (ex.InnerException.Message.ToString().Length > 0)
                    {
                        if (ex.InnerException.Message.ToString().Length > 2048)
                        {
                            ApplicationError myInnerException = new ApplicationError();
                            myInnerException.ErrorNumber = 1;
                            myInnerException.ErrorSeverity = 1;
                            myInnerException.ErrorState = 1;
                            myInnerException.ErrorLine = 29;
                            myInnerException.ErrorProcedure = "Web Service - INNER EXCEPTION";
                            myInnerException.ErrorMessage = ex.InnerException.Message.ToString().Substring(0, 2047);
                            myInnerException.ErrorDateTime = DateTime.Now;

                            context.ApplicationErrors.AddObject(myInnerException);
                            context.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ApplicationError myInnerException = new ApplicationError();
                            myInnerException.ErrorNumber = 1;
                            myInnerException.ErrorSeverity = 1;
                            myInnerException.ErrorState = 1;
                            myInnerException.ErrorLine = 29;
                            myInnerException.ErrorProcedure = "Web Service - INNER EXCEPTION";
                            myInnerException.ErrorMessage = ex.InnerException.Message.ToString();
                            myInnerException.ErrorDateTime = DateTime.Now;

                            context.ApplicationErrors.AddObject(myInnerException);
                            context.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You should really refactor that code. The blocks creating, populating and saving the `ApplicationError` instances can easily be factored out into a method.

Comment: WHat does this mean? `if (ex.Message.ToString().Length > 2048)` looks suspicious

Comment: @sll the only difference is, that he "substrings" the message to only 2048 characters - hence my suggestion to refactor.

Comment: I am checking the length of the message because my message field in my database table is limited in size.  This is just telling me to trim it down.  I could just take that out and trim it regardless.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no inner exception, there's no inner exception.

From here: [How to: Check an Exception's Inner Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdwz4c0s%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

> If there is no original error, the value of InnerException will be a
>   null reference or Nothing in Visual Basic.

The message  "See inner exception for details." is probably someone's boilerplate text and not always applicable.

Comment: I understand if there is no inner exception then there isn't one.  That is why I am checking the length of the inner exception before I log it.    I don't however think that the "See inner exception for details." is a boilerplate message in this case.  The service is failing for some reason, but I just can't figure out what it is.  I only get this message every once in a while, but I haven't figured out what is causing it.

Comment: You still need the null-check.  Check to see if the `InnerException` property is null first, don't just check the length of the `Message` property.  That will cause a null reference exception to be thrown.

Comment: I changed it to check for null.